# Why is ContentResolver.query() returning duplicate entries from contacts?

Tags: android, duplicates, cursor, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

So I'm reading in these contacts using Android's native implementation, using a test phone with about 1,056 contacts on it. The problem I'm having is that it's rather slow, so I'm logging the outcomes of my cursor.moveToNext(), and seeing that it's reading in contacts past the last in an overlapping, duplicating fashion. It does, however, have previous logic implemented so the app compares the hashed version of this list of entries to the previously saved one every second... which eventually brings the entries back to the correct value, order, and contents. However, using the code below, at worst it's pulling the entire contact list AGAIN, and then putting it in there with the same list (essentially reads the same address book twice and reads it in, doubling entries). This gets worse the larger your contact list is (smaller books, like this Galaxy I have with 9 contacts, don't seem to be affected; whereas my phone with about 106 is slightly, and this tester with 1,053 significantly) with the larger phones I've tested taking upwards of *a minute and a half to two minutes* before it's fully updated, accurate, and done.

What's confusing is that it somehow, even after all this duplication, the check manages to come back and be *exactly* what it was supposed to be (i.e 1,053 contact phone I see it adding the 2,106th row, then it immediately loads the proper 1,053 contact book).

Here's how my cursor is defined:

```
Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(addressBookURI, 
CONTACTS_QUERY_PROJECTION, CONTACTS_QUERY_SELECTION, null, CONTACTS_QUERY_SORT);
```

Here's each of the components of said Cursor "c":

```
    private static final Uri addressBookURI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.REMOVE_DUPLICATE_ENTRIES, "1").build();

    private static final String[] CONTACTS_QUERY_PROJECTION = {
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.Data.DATA1,
        ContactsContract.Data.DATA2,
        "account_name"
    };
    
    private static final String CONTACTS_QUERY_SELECTION = "in_default_directory=1 and has_phone_number=1 and mimetype='vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2'";
    private static final String CONTACTS_QUERY_SORT = "contact_id ASC";
```

Processing the Cursor "c"'s reads:

```
            List<String[]> entries = new ArrayList<>();
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
            String id = c.getString(0);
            String name = c.getString(2);
            String phone = c.getString(3);
            String type = c.getString(4);
            String account_name = c.getString(5);
            Log.d(sTag, "contact:row:" + id + ":" + name + ":" + phone + ":" + type + ":" + 
            account_name);
            
            entries.add(new String[]{id, name, phone, type});
```

It's in that Log.d() statement where I can see duplicates of contacts, wherein the only difference between the original contact and follow-up duplicates is the "id" variable (keeps increasing, period).

For example (if it happened with smaller amounts of contacts; all values are made up):

contact:row:1:Maurine Lastpass:4145737719:3:D8:0B:9A:CC:88:BF

contact:row:2:Blondell Sosig:4013008122:3:D8:0B:9A:CC:88:BF

contact:row:3:Amber Altingle:8885554422:2:D8:0B:9A:CC:88:BF

contact:row:4:Frank Helgenson:8885554422:2:D8:0B:9A:CC:88:BF

contact:row:5:Hiro Xin:8885554422:2:D8:0B:9A:CC:88:BF

contact:row:6:Baley Balix:6316773675:2:D8:0B:9A:CC:88:BF

contact:row:7:Henry Halgor:6316773675:2:D8:0B:9A:CC:88:BF

contact:row:8:Hammy Xevronic:6316773675:2:D8:0B:9A:CC:88:BF

contact:row:9:Maurine Lastpass:4145737719:3:D8:0B:9A:CC:88:BF

contact:row:10:Blondell Sosig:4013008122:3:D8:0B:9A:CC:88:BF

contact:row:11:Amber Altingle:8885554422:2:D8:0B:9A:CC:88:BF

contact:row:12:Frank Helgenson:8885554422:2:D8:0B:9A:CC:88:BF

contact:row:13:Hiro Xin:8885554422:2:D8:0B:9A:CC:88:BF

contact:row:14:Baley Balix:6316773675:2:D8:0B:9A:CC:88:BF

contact:row:15:Henry Halgor:6316773675:2:D8:0B:9A:CC:88:BF

contact:row:16:Hammy Xevronic:6316773675:2:D8:0B:9A:CC:88:BF

I've tried storing the very first contact and letting it read from the Cursor until it matches up with that contact, but since the "id" variable keeps increasing, it makes the contact different enough to be ignored. I removed the ID portion of the contact, changed the URI from the default to one with an explicit REMOVE_DUPLICATE_ENTRIES = 1 parameter on it, and I tried to bring in the "real" count using ContactsContract.Data._COUNT in order to check the number of entries on the cursor against it, but that just crashes with "no such column _COUNT".

Is there any reason why the cursor would be pulling duplicate contacts like this? Is there something wrong with the structure of my query that is causing this sort of duplication?

Answer (score 1):

let's recap the way ContactsContract DB is organized:

1. Contacts table - contains one row per contact, but hardly any information
2. RawContacts table - can have multiple rows, each assigned to a single contact-ID (from the previous table), contains a logical group of multiple Data rows usually for a single SyncProvider such as Google.
3. Data table - contains the actual data of a RawContact, each row has a MIMETYPE column which states what kind of data this row is about (phone, email, name, etc.) + 15 data columns to hold the information itself.

There are also pseudo tables, such as `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` which you are querying in your code, which basically queries over the Data table but with a specific MIMETYPE value, for example `Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`.

In your code you are querying over CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI which means you are asking for all the different phone numbers in the DB.
So if a single contact has 3 phone numbers, you will get 3 rows for that contact (each with a different phone number).

However looking at your output, it seems like every contact has a single phone number in the DB, but it looks like the contacts themselves are duplicated.
So for example `Amber Altingle` has contact ID 3 and also 11, which means you have two separate contacts named `Amber Altingle`.
This is not duplication in the query code, but possibly duplication in the contact creation code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and answer! I very much appreciate it. In terms of the reply, though, I do want to say I've tested this with other devices with less contacts, and certainly no duplicates, and still had the same issue of it bringing in anywhere from the first 1/4 to the entire address book in a second time. I did end up gating it by locally saving the first contact's name and number, then checking for it before reading each row. This seems to work pretty well, but I'm still concerned about the potential edge cases.

Comment: i'm not sure about your other devices, but the output you sent in your post makes it clear you have two copies of a contact named "Amber Altingle". If you open the built-in contacts app you may not see it in the default view, but you need to find a way to view "All contacts" (possibly in settings) and then you should see the duplicate contact appearing

Comment: That could be the case on the larger 1,053 contact device, but I don't see any additional settings to reveal more contacts (I did see an option to delete duplicates, though, so I did that, which removed about 5 contacts). Also, I have my personal phone with about 109 contacts on it, no duplicates in any way, and it'd still overreach and read in the first half or so of my contact list again.